# Why input has empty value on mobile device in form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have such form:

```
<section class="newsletter m_footer footer-group footer-section m_decorated js_newsletter">
<form
    action="{{ domain }}/?action=test/subscribe"
    method="post"
    class="newsletterForm newsletter-form m_footer google-recaptcha-newsletter"
    id="footerNewsletter"
    novalidate
>
    <input
        class="newsletter-form__input"
        type="text"
        name="email"
        required
        data-error="field_required"
        data-error="clang_newsletter_subscription_failed"
    />
    <button type="submit" name="subscribe" class="newsletter-form__btn button medium ghostWhite check-form">
        <span>Submit</span>
    </button>
</form> 
</section>
```

And when I use this function I always get input with empty value (although I field it with some value). On Desktop it works fine but on mobile it always empty. I also tried to delete `event.preventDefault()` but it did not help.

```
    $('.newsletterForm').submit((event) => {
   
        event.preventDefault();
        let $form = $(event.target).closest('form');
        
        let $required = $form.find('input:required').filter((index, element) => {
            return $(element).val().length === 0;
        });
});
```

Can it be cause by captha script?

```
<script>
var renderRecaptcha = {};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  $('#footerNewsletter input[name=email],#blogNewsletter input[name=email],#contactForm textarea[name=message]').on('focus', function() {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    if (!document.getElementById('recaptcha')) {
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit&onload=onScriptLoad&hl={{ shopname.short }}';
      script.id = 'recaptcha';
      head.appendChild(script);
    }

    $('#footerNewsletter input[name=email],#blogNewsletter input[name=email],#contactForm textarea[name=message]').off('focus');
  });
});
function onScriptLoad() {
};

window.onSubmit = function (token) {
    $('.google-recaptcha').submit();
};

window.onSubmitNewsletterFooter = function (token) {
    $('#footerNewsletter').submit();
};

window.onSubmitSendQuestion = function (token) {
    const $questionForm = $('.js_question-form');

    $questionForm.data('recaptcha-response', token);
    $questionForm.submit();
};

window.onSubmitSendReview = function (token) {
    const $reviewForm = $('.js_review-form');

    $reviewForm.data('recaptcha-response', token);
    $reviewForm.submit();
};

window.onSubmitNewsletterBlog = function (token) {
    $('.blog-newsletter').submit();
};

window.runRecaptcha = function(cssElement) {
    let element = $(cssElement);
    let renderRecaptchaId;
    if (element.length != 1) {
        return false;
    }
    let idForm = element.closest('form').attr('id');
    if (renderRecaptcha.hasOwnProperty(idForm)) {
      renderRecaptchaId = renderRecaptcha[idForm];
      grecaptcha.execute(renderRecaptchaId);
      return;
    }

    let sitekeyValue = element.data('sitekey');
    let callbackFunction = element.data('callback') || 'onSubmit';
    renderRecaptchaId = grecaptcha.render(element[0], {
        'sitekey': sitekeyValue,
        'size': 'invisible',
        'callback': callbackFunction
    });
    renderRecaptcha[idForm] = renderRecaptchaId;
    grecaptcha.execute(renderRecaptchaId);
}
```

Comment: You are not doing anything with the value in your sample code currently. Can you please add that part so that it becomes clearer? What browsers are you using on desktop v mobile?

Comment: Yes it’s quite likely that the Captcha interferes. But this changes the nature of your question quite much. I have no idea how reCaptcha changes your forms. Have you tried addressing your email input with an ID?

Answer (score 0):

`$required` will only be the required input if it’s empty.

The [`filter()` function](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) will only **keep** elements from the set of matched elements for whom the provided function **returns true**.

So currently you will have `$required = [<input required …>]` if it’s empty, and you will have `$required = []` if it’s value contains something.

You’ll probably need to turn your condition around. Also, you can simplify your code:

```js
const $required = $form.find('input:required').filter((index, element) => $(element).val().length > 0);
```

Based on the code you provided, I would have the following remarks:

- Your input field does not have any label, which is very bad for usability and accessibility. Add a `<label>Email Address <input…></label>`
- use `<input type="email">` if it’s meant for email addresses. This will offer an optimised on-screen keyboard on touchscreen devices
- `let $form = $(event.target).closest('form')` is terribly complicated, you can use `const $form =` [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)
- It’s great that you added `required` even though you added `novalidate` to the form. Your browser will not use this attribute for anything, but you are exposing to assistive technology that the input is, indeed, required

Here is all together:

```js
$('.newsletterForm').submit(event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const $form = $(event.currentTarget);

  const $required = $form.find('input:required').filter((index, element) => $(element).val().length > 0);
  
  console.log($required.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="newsletter m_footer footer-group footer-section m_decorated js_newsletter">
  <form action="/?action=test/subscribe" method="post" class="newsletterForm newsletter-form m_footer google-recaptcha-newsletter" id="footerNewsletter" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Subscribe to our newsletter</legend>
      <label>Email Address
        <input class="newsletter-form__input" type="email" name="email" required data-error="field_required" data-error="clang_newsletter_subscription_failed" />
      </label>
      <button type="submit" name="subscribe" class="newsletter-form__btn button medium ghostWhite check-form">
        <span>Submit</span>
      </button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: in my case I don't have value from input, it's empty string

Comment: Does the above code snippet work on your phone?

Comment: yes it works on my phone

Comment: added script with captcha. can it cause this propblem?